# Skipped tests are not displayed in the Cucumber Report

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm running my Cucumber tests using `mvn clean verify`. I have annotated a test scenario with the `@Skip` tag and then provided this tag inside `@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @Skip")` in order to skip that scenario. 
 After running the tests I get the following log: `[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0.` 
What am I missing in order to show that the test was skipped? 
I would expect to see:
`[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1.`

Comment: There is not enough information here to make a determination. Where's your runner code? What is the path to your step definition files? etc...

Answer (score 0):

When using a tag filter with Cucumber and JUnit 4, scenarios are excluded (filtered) from execution. So JUnit doesn't even tell Surefire about their existence and so they don't get counted.

Why? Mostly a coincidence of history that takes too long to explain.

When using cucumbers tag filters with JUnit 5 scenarios are correctly marked as skipped. Though oddly enough when using JUnit5s own tag filters they're not included. Though the semantics are such that both behaviors are correct now.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine